# storeassetd keeps crashing repeatedly. Cannot open Mac App Store

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

When I try to open the Mac App Store, I always get a blank screen with a loading animation. I tried resetting NVRAM settings, but it didn't help.

[image: App store stuck]

I examined the console logs and found that a demon named 'storeassetd' is crashing repeatedly every few seconds. Here is the crash report:

```
Process:               storeassetd [5481]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd
Identifier:            storeassetd
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           storeassetd [5481]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-11-22 19:07:41.182 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1108)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        53B9A111-7B8D-E1E2-448D-D7BE42CDA6AA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1B24A29E-A8DE-4A4F-9928-A5A98B1ED870

Time Awake Since Boot: 3100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _kDefaultsMajorOSUpdateNotificationDelayKey
  Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd
  Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/StoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd
```

Due to this issue, I'm not able to install any new apps from the App Store. My last option is to reinstall the OS, but I wanted to check if there is any other way to fix this issue.

Thanks.